# Why is abelianness such a precious property?

Tags: abstract-algebra, intuition, abelian-groups

My abstract algebra teacher said the other day that constructions like ideals and cosets and normal subgroups are "trying to capture a little bit of abelianness." He has used phrases like "magic happens" when speaking of this property, or qualities that mimic commutativity in some way. So why is it such a game-changing quality?

Thanks!

Comment: In general, abelian things are significantly easier to work with, and as a result more is known about them. As for ideals and normal subgroups "trying to capture a bit of abelieness", I wouldn't think of them like that. I'd prefer to think of them as kernels of homomorphisms.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For one, in studying an abelian group you can utilize a lot of your intuition from doing addition.

But more to the point about normal subgroups - One should note that in an abelian group $G$, every subgroup $H$ is normal, so you can always take the quotient $G/H$.  In a non-abelian group, you need special conditions on $H$.  The definition of a normal subgroup is a subgroup  $H$ such that when $h\in H$, $ghg^{-1}\in H$ for every $g\in G$.  You can see how this condition is trivial when G is abelian.  But in the non-abelian case it's just what is needed for the quotient $G/H$ to be a group.  I think this might be what your teacher meant when he said normal subgroups are "trying to capture a little bit of abelianness" - they do something that every subgroup can do in an abelian group.

Of course, this really doesn't even start the whole picture.  I can't talk about every example, but here, in a nutshell, is one I've been trying to understand: Let $K$ be a [number field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_number_field).  It turns out that the field $K$ itself (in particular, it's group of [fractional ideals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_ideal)) has enough information to describe all of it's abelian [extensions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_extension), that is, the extensions whose [galois group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galois_group) is abelian.  What about the non-abelian extensions?  Oh, we don't even know.  That's an [open research area](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Langlands_program).

Many times, groups can be attached to another more complicated object (like a number field, in the above example) to tell us something about that object.  When these groups are abelian, it often means these objects are particularly nice and well-behaved.

But we also just know a lot more about abelian groups themselves.  For instance, every finite abelian group is isomorphic to a direct product of cyclic groups of prime power order.  What can we say about every finite non-abelian group?  We don't know them all, but we know they can get [really complicated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classification_of_finite_simple_groups)

Comment: +1, but a typo: you want "prime *power* order" in the last paragraph.

Comment: not a typo, actually, but me not remembering properly all my facts about finite abelian groups. :)

Comment: I'd give you a +1, but it'd be setting the bar too high for all others so I can't ;)